# MySql sort ascendingly conditionally

Tags: mysql, sorting

Trying to sort rows from lowest to highest continually, or rather repeatedly using MySql. For example: if a column has the following values: 1,3,2,4,2,1,4,3,5, then it should end up like this 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4. So it goes from lowest to highest, but tries to sort again from lowest to highest multiple times.

Comment: Is there some other column that determines the basis for when the sort "starts over"?

Comment: @Mike no, there's no other column.

Comment: This is likely a futile exercise as how would you determine which row with value `1` goes into the first slot and which goes in to subsequent slots for `1`?  What happens when the data set looks like `1,5,4,5,4,3` or something like that where you don't have number of `1`'s >= number of `2`'s >= number of `3`'s, etc. i think you need to rethink your approach if you need that kind of sort, or you will need to implement the logic at the application level.

Comment: @Strawberry There's a PK column but I can't use the PK column since records are inserted randomly. The column that I'm describing is a column that says who basically is the owner for an asset.

Comment: @MikeBrant Looking at your dataset 1,5,4,5,4,3 it would end up like this: 1,3,4,5,4,5, but if MySql has no tools for this, I will have to do it at the application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large sets, the semi-JOIN operation (the approach in the answer from Strawberry) may create an unwieldy resultset. (Then again, MySQL may have some optimizations in there.)

Another alternative available in MySQL is to use "user variables", like this:

```
SELECT r.mycol
  FROM ( SELECT IF(q.mycol=@prev,@seq := @seq + 1,@seq := 1) AS seq
              , @prev := q.mycol AS mycol
           FROM mytable q
           JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @seq := NULL) p
          ORDER BY q.mycol
       ) r
 ORDER BY r.seq, r.mycol
```

Let me unpack that a bit, and explain what it's doing, starting with the inner query (inline view aliased as `r`.) We're telling MySQL to get the column (`mycol`) containing the values you want to sort, e.g. 1,3,2,4,2,1,4,3,5 and we're telling MySQL to order these in ascending sequence:  1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5.

The "trick" now is to use a MySQL user variable, so that we can compare the `mycol` value from the current row to the `mycol` value from the previous row, and we use that to assign an ascending sequence value, from 1..n on each distinct value.

With that resultset, we can tell MySQL to order by that assigned sequence value first, and then by the value from `mycol`.

---

If there is a unique id on each row, then a correlated subquery can be used to get an equivalent result (although this approach is very unlikely to perform as well on large sets)

```
 SELECT r.mycol
   FROM mytable r
  ORDER
     BY ( SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM mytable q
           WHERE q.mycol = r.mycol
             AND q.id <= r.id
        )
      , r.mycol
```

Here's the setup for the test case:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT, mycol INT);
INSERT INTO mytable (id, mycol) VALUES 
(1,1),(2,3),(3,2),(4,4),(5,2),(6,1),(7,4),(8,3),(9,5);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I ended up implementing my solution using the strategy with mysql user variables.

Answer (score 0):

there is no order two time just this

```
   ORDER BY column ASC
```

Comment: That will simply make it 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend that the PK is a unique integer. Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE seq(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,val INT);

INSERT INTO seq VALUES (8,1),(4,2),(1,3),(2,4),(7,0),(6,1),(3,2),(5,5);

SELECT * FROM seq ORDER BY val;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  7 |    0 |
|  6 |    1 |
|  8 |    1 |
|  3 |    2 |
|  4 |    2 |
|  1 |    3 |
|  2 |    4 |
|  5 |    5 |
+----+------+

SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) rank 
  FROM seq x 
  JOIN seq y 
    ON y.val = x.val 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY id 
 ORDER 
    BY rank
     , val;
+----+------+------+
| id | val  | rank |
+----+------+------+
|  7 |    0 |    1 |
|  6 |    1 |    1 |
|  3 |    2 |    1 |
|  1 |    3 |    1 |
|  2 |    4 |    1 |
|  5 |    5 |    1 |
|  8 |    1 |    2 |
|  4 |    2 |    2 |
+----+------+------+
```